# Ember get route currently transitioning to

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'd like to know if it's possible to get the route my ember app is currently transitioning to, from a Ember.Service?

The console is available to display it: `Attempting transition to users.details` so I suppose this is available somewhere?

Where can I find this information?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this in your route in the `willTransition` event:

```
App.SomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    willTransition: function(transition) {
      // transition.targetName
    }
  }
});
```

You could send this to a controller managing application history that is injected on all application controllers or set it as a property on the route, depending where your service is being injected.

If you provide info about the kind of service you're using I can give a more specific answer.